# ¿Por qué el operador & actua de manera extraña en este programa?

Tags: c++

Al asignar a @eightflags el valor de eightflags & mask3 (línea 18), se le asigna 'false', cuando @eightflags es igual a @mask3, y @mask3 & @mask3 es 'true'.

¿Por qué ocurre esto? Gracias de antemano.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const unsigned char mask0 = 0;      // 0000 0000
    const unsigned char mask1 = 1 << 1; // 0000 0010
    const unsigned char mask2 = 1 << 2; // 0000 0100
    const unsigned char mask3 = 1 << 3; // 0000 1000
    const unsigned char mask4 = 1 << 4; // 0001 0000
    const unsigned char mask5 = 1 << 5; // 0010 0000
    const unsigned char mask6 = 1 << 6; // 0100 0000
    const unsigned char mask7 = 1 << 7; // 1000 0000

    bool eightflags = mask3; //eightflags es true
    cout << eightflags; //couts 1
    eightflags &= mask3; /* eightflags es false pero debería ser true porque
    mask3 & mask3 es true y eightflags = mask3

    0000 1000
    0000 1000
    &--------
    0000 1000 
    */
    cout << eightflags; //couts 0
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Primero, partes de una premisa falsa, **`mask3` no es igual que `eightflags`**, al hacer:

```
bool eightflags = mask3;
```

tiene lugar un **casting implícito** de tu `char` (8) a `bool`, quedando `eightflags` como `true` (1).

La conversión a `bool` considera cero (para los tipos numéricos) y el puntero nulo como `false` y cualquier otro valor como`true`.

Dado que operas a nivel de bits, lo relevante es la representación binaria de ambas:

> ```
> eightflags -> 0000 0001    
> mask       -> 0000 1000
> ```

A continuación haces:

```
 eightflags &= mask3;
```

lo que es lo mismo que:

```
 eightflags = eightflags & mask3;
```

pero recuerda que no usas un `and` lógico (`&&`), que si resultaría en `true`, estás operando a nivel de bits, por lo que el `and` se aplica bit a bit:

> 0 & 0 es 0
>   0 & 1 es 0
>   1 & 0 es 0
>   1 & 1 es 1

lo cual, gráficamente en tu caso podemos representar algo así:

> ```
> eightflags -> 0000 0001   
>   &           &&&& &&&&
> mask       -> 0000 1000
>   ↓           ↓↓↓↓ ↓↓↓↓
> eightflags -> 0000 0000
> ```

por lo que `eightflags` termina siendo `false` (0).

> **Observación**: a diferencia de `char` cuyo tamaño es siempre uno,  `bool` no tiene un tamaño  definido en el estándar, pudiendo variar según la implementación. Comúnmente es 1 también (unidad mínima de memoria direccionable del sistema, comúnmente 1 byte/8 bits), pero no podemos dar por sentado esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Entonces, al asignar a eighflags el valor de mask3, simplemente se le asigna 'true' en la forma 0000 0001, no?

Comment: Efectivamente, como `mask3` en esencia es un valor numérico y no es 0 (es 8), al hacer el casting se evalúa como verdadero, `true`, que  en esencia es 1.  La representación binaria en memoria no tiene por que ser  `0000 0001`, podría ser `0000 0000 0000 0001` por ejemplo.`bool` no tiene un tamaño definido por el estándar, aunque comúnmente usa la cantidad minima de memoria direccionable (8 bits por lo general) no podemos darlo por sentado como si se puede hacer con `char`. He añadido una pequeña nota a la respuesta.